# c# Regex, how can I escape [[ and ]]

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to instantiate a new `Regex` class with the regular expression

`var reg = new Regex("[[" + token.Key + "]]");`

But I'm getting the following error

`System.ArgumentException: 'parsing "[[Impact]]" - [x-y] range in reverse order.'`

How can I instantiate the new class with the double square brackets in the regular expression?

Comment: Did you try `"\\[\\[" + token.Key + "\\]\\]"`?

Comment: First of all, interestingly I don't get such an exception. On the other hand, what you are trying to achieve? you want the regex to match [[ and ]] as literals?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I'll try `\\[\\[` and see what happens

Comment: @ZorgoZ Yes That's what I want.

Comment: @ZorgoZ According to my duplicate down vote which isn't really a duplicate, but very informative none the less,  it might be a different flavor of regex you're using.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I did not know that .net has different flavors of RegEx. I was using the latest one in LinqPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the characters "[" and "]" for the regular expression, and if you are using "\" to escape the brackets, then you need to escape those in your C# string as well.

That means it can be either:

```
"\\[\\[" + key + "]]"
```

or

```
@"\[\[" + key + "]]"
```

or

```
Regex.Escape("[[") + key + "]]"
```

You don't need to escape the latter "]" because Regex recognizes them as normal characters if you don't have an unescaped "[" before them. I tried it on [Regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=104272) (a regex testing website) and other answers suggest it as well.

Comment: Thanks, everyone had good answers but this one gives an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You could use built-in functions to escape things:

```
var re = Regex.Escape("[[") + token.Key + Regex.Escape("]]");
var reg = new Regex(re);
```

But you may also want to escape the `token.Key`?

Or just use a `string.Contains(...)`, if you don't want the special features of regex.

Comment: apparently, the set of closing brackets do not need to be escaped. I tried it on regexpal: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=104272

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann Yes that is true, inspecting the escaped string shows that also. But when they are not known literals, you might want to play it safe.

Comment: Of course that is absolutely correct. I just mentioned it because in case anyone didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\[\[" + token.Key + @"]]");
```

[image]

(Note: the second @ is not actually needed)

Update:
This is even better:

```
var reg = new Regex($@"\[\[{token.Key}]]");
```

Comment: what is that extension called?

Comment: This screenshot is a LinqPad snippet. `.Dump` is part of it, but this is something similar: https://github.com/victorjspinto/101-Linq-Samples/blob/master/LINQ%20-%20Quantifiers/C%23/Quantifiers/ObjectDumper.cs

Comment: @vc74 yes, I have already noted that, as you can see

Answer (score 1):

Just escape every bracket with a bracket like is shown below:

```
var reg = new Regex("[[[["+ token.Key +"]]]]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var reg = new Regex("[[][[]" + token.Key + "[]][]]");
```

it will match, for example `[[Impact]]` if `token.Key` equals `"Impact"`.